# What are the actual physical effects if the relative permittivity of a dielectric increases?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

I learn some basic information about the [relative permittivity](https://www.tau.ac.il/%7Etsirel/dump/Static/knowino.org/wiki/Relative_permittivity.html). I can understand that when the relative permittivity $\epsilon_r \to \infty$ that material is a perfect conductor. On the other hand, for any finite value of $\epsilon_r$, that material is a perfect dielectric.

However, I need help to obtain an intuitional or qualitative understanding of a specific physical setting, that is, two-layer different materials, a dielectric (diel_A) and a vacuum, between two plates (electrodes) with a fixed external electric field. In this case, what is the actual physical effect, or what happens if the relative permittivity of "diel_A" increases? Thank you in advance!

Comment: A perfect conductor has permittivity of *negative* infinity.

Answer (score 1):

For a parallel plate capacitor without any dielectric material
$$C_0=\frac{\epsilon_0 A}{s}$$

Now consider a simple situation where you have a capacitor with a half-filled dielectric with dielectric constant $\kappa$ (same as relative permittivity).
$$\frac{1}{C_s}=\frac{1}{C_v}+\frac{1}{C_d}$$
Putting $C_v=A\epsilon_0/(s/2)$ and $C_d=A\kappa \epsilon_0/(s/2)$ will give
$$C_s=\frac{2\kappa }{\kappa +1}C_0$$
$$\lim_{\kappa\rightarrow -\infty}C_s=2C_0$$
The explanation for this can be understood from [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/62447/247238). It's clear that if $s\rightarrow s/2$ so that $C_0\rightarrow 2C_0$.

Edit: The notation is as follows

- $s$ stands for the distance between the plate.
- $C_s$ is the combined capacitance.
- $C_v$ is the capacitance of the vacuum part.
- $C_d$ is the capacitance of the dielectric part.
- $\epsilon_0$ is the permittivity of free space.

Comment: thank you for the help, could you explain the notations? For example, what is $\epsilon_0$ and $s$?

Comment: I added notations. :)